# Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When an edit has been suggested on a question by an SO user with low rep, if I go to approve it (assuming I'm the first to do so) there's still a requirement for further approval. Why is this needed?

I can single-handedly edit questions myself without anyone's approval and even single-handedly close certain questions as duplicates if they are tagged with something I hold a gold badge for.

So why can't I single-handedly approve an edit which basically covers what I would have done anyway?

**EDIT:** As Plutonix has commented it seems there is a workaround, not sure if it's really that which is intended but you can also :

Select Improve when you view it (as a Question, not in the Review Queue), then save it with or without changes.

Comment: Select Improve when you view it (as a Question, not in the Review Queue), then save it with or without changes.  You're right though, a workaround should not be needed.

Comment: @Plutonix : Yes that's an option but it is a bit of a workaround.

Comment: I'd quite like to see this. But only on suggested edits opened "directly" from the edit link under the question or answer. I suspect (but have no evidence for this) that the quality of these organically found reviews might be better than those from people working their way through a review queue.

Comment: @MartinSmith : Very good point. I rarely have time to go through the "review" section. Pretty much everything I want to edit (or suggested edits I want to approve) is done through the "edit" link on questions themselves.

Comment: @Squonk and it is only in that context that you are likely to care if it hangs there in limbo as well. My theory is that these edits are more likely to be made by people with relevant tag expertise so they ought to be better ( and also they see the whole context from that route)

Comment: I think this would be a good opportunity for a combo-requirement, ie "Once you hit 10K rep, and once you hit 1,000 reviews of a given type, and once you have a gold badge in any tag, then you can single-handedly approve suggested edits for that review type that have that tag associated with them".

Comment: I've created a new meta post asking for a feature to work like @MartinSmith mentions, i.e. only when clicking the "Edit (#)" link on a question.  It's here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/proposal-let-experienced-users-approve-edits-when-they-view-the-question-first

Comment: It's worth noting that you actually *can* effectively do this by using the "Improve Edit" option.

Comment: Every single time I see an edit that looks good I'm like yeah sure, so I click "Approve".  WRONG.  On some tags it can take weeks for edits to get fully approved - and the worst part about it is there's no way to reverse my decision so I can go back and **Improve** , do nothing and then save it - which is just a bit ridiculous.  At the very least, we should have the ability to reverse the decision to approve an edit.

Comment: I don't wanna imagine what the robo-reviewers would do if it only took 1 review...

Comment: The workaround suggested in the Edit has a downside. The new user that suggested the edit doesn't end up showing as the editor. This is a poor experience for someone that is a new participant in the site and is working to improve other people's experience with suggested edits. Though this question is old, it still feels wrong that two approvers are needed and that such a workaround exists.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because there has been a long (and still ongoing) problem of users incorrectly reviewing suggested edits, despite having the privilege to edit posts without review.  Too many people simply don't put in the attention to evaluating edits that they do in actually making them.

Comment: Which leads me to believe that we should have a better system for detecting when these types of things happen and dealing with the users more effectively. But, then again, we've discussed that before.

Comment: OK, I can see that argument up to a point but surely there *should* be some level of "rep" where a SO user could approve suggested edits single-handedly? Perhaps I pay a great attention to detail when others don't but it does seem like a bit of a hassle. Unless I reject the edit and re-edit (in exactly the same way) there's no telling when another approval will come along if I simply vote to approve.

Comment: @Squonk Given that we've seen users with tens of thousands of rep going through the review queues approving everything, no, that is very clearly not an option at all.  If there is a way to distinguish which reviewers actually evaluate edits well and will take the proper action in just about every case then we haven't found it, and it's not rep.

Comment: Nope, definitely not rep. We almost need a review board of reviewers but that's not very efficient or practical

Comment: @codeMagic And then the reviewer reviewers will be just as bad as the reviewers, so we'll need reviewers for the reviewer reviewers, and then those reviewers won't do a good job, so we'll need reviewers for the reviewer reviewer reviewers, and they won't do a good job so we'll...

Comment: So basically there's a subtle flaw in the system. My reference to "rep" was purely because at a certain rep level a user can single-handedly make edits and it just seemed odd they couldn't single-handedly approve suggested edits. I guess I'll just have to live with it although it's sometimes frustrating.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said it isn't very practical. They would have to be specially selected by people who were specially selected by the specially selected people...

Comment: @Servy : Check the comments by Martin Smith on my question. It seems if a SO user can single-handedly close (put on hold) a question based on holding a gold badge, they could also approve a suggested edit as long as it was done from the question itself rather than from the review queue. As Martin suggests, if I'm looking at a question from the normal questions list it's because I want to see if I can answer it. If I want to edit (or approve an edit) it's because I understand the where / what needs editing to improve it.

Comment: @Squonk You're more than welcome to suggest that feature, although it does have its fair share of flags, such as users using the /review queue but taking the extra click to go to the question before approving/rejecting it.

Comment: @Servy: Well I think we've discussed enough and I understand the way the things work as they are now so I'll accept your answer and explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @codeMagic There's no impracticality whatsoever. Just elect them (there's never any shortage of people running in elections) based on peer votes. During elections, we get a handy link to see their review history, including their top 20 most debated review choices (suggested edits that made it through with at least two rejections, or that didn't make it through with at least two approvals, etc.). I've been suggesting a dedicated panel to audit (an actual audit, not the "test" that we deal with today) reviews for a while now.

Comment: Again referring to Martin Smith's comment on the question: does this also apply to users who approve edits from the edit link directly on the question or answer, or only to those who do so from the edit queue? If the behavior is different, maybe the rules should be different.

Comment: @abarnert Again, if you want to propose a feature to special case that situation, again, you're more than welcome to propose it.  It does have some potential pitfalls, but it's certainly something that you can discuss/propose if you want.

Comment: Can Jon Skeet approve edits single-handedly?

Comment: @DonRoby Sure, when the edit is on a post he authored.

Comment: @abarnert: I have just proposed something like this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/proposal-let-experienced-users-approve-edits-when-they-view-the-question-first

Comment: It should take context into account. If you're working through the review queue, then absolutely require two approvals. If you were just viewing the question anyway, want to make an edit, and have the required rep to do so, and the question is previously edited for review with the same or similar edit, it's incredibly annoying to need to wait for another approver... especially if this edit is significant for viewing the question (ie: fixing code formatting). I **frequently** find myself making meaningless "additional improvements" just so I can get a reasonable view of code in a question.

Comment: I don't use the review queues, because they are out of my way, barely discoverable and have no associated incentive. I constantly try to edit posts (internal motivation) and get impeded by pending edit suggestions. I have complained about this many, many times. I [continue to believe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420357/523612) that approving suggested edits single-handedly should still be possible.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Funny that your linked post is mostly complaining about the guidance against people making trivial edits that don't meaningfully improve a post, and are saying that such edits should be encouraged, while here you're complaining about how you're unable to make edits to meaningfully approve posts due to there being pending suggested edits on them.  People making trivial edits that don't meaningfully improve a post but require reviews to review them is precisely what's impeding you.

Comment: But to your other point, reviews require multiple people to review them *because so many people review improperly*, and it's simply necessary.  If enough people actually reviewed things properly and didn't either make mistakes, or more commonly and concerningly, negligently not even make a good faith effort to try to review properly, it wouldn't be necessary.  The frequency in which people abuse the review system is precisely why protections, such as the requirements to number of reviews, are needed.

Comment: "while here you're complaining about how you're unable to make edits to meaningfully [improve] posts due to there being pending suggested edits on them." Yes; that's a technical problem, not a social problem. In both cases, the problem is resolved by just letting me approve the edit myself, and then building upon it.

Comment: "reviews require multiple people to review them because so many people review improperly, and it's simply necessary." I just finished explaining that I'm not using the review queue. *Of course* I can easily tell whether the edit is good or bad when I'm about to make my own edit. I've **just been** evaluating the post in order to understand what should be edited and how! "The frequency in which people abuse the review system" Is there real evidence for this? Are the bad reviews coming from people who would make good edits themselves? I think the problem is the queue itself.

Comment: For one example off the top of my head: what if I could add `haspendingedit:1` to searches, instead of letting the system decide which pending edits to show me?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel " the problem is resolved by just letting me approve the edit myself, and then building upon it"  You literally already have that ability.  And have for like a decade.  "Is there real evidence for this?"  Yes.  Lots.  It's so obvious to anyone doing any reviewing that you can't not see it constantly.  "Are the bad reviews coming from people who would make good edits themselves?"  Yes, it's not an issue exclusive to low rep users. "what if I could add haspendingedit:1 to searches" What does this do to address any problems, either yours or those involving abuse?

Comment: "You literally already have that ability." It's labelled in a way that implies that I will somehow steal credit for the other person's change, if I recognize it at all. "What does this do to address any problems" it would allow users to review edits for things they're actually interested in improving, which would make them more invested in the process of review, which would result in them not abusively trying to get past edits and accept other stuff in order to complete their self-assigned "homework". It would also allow getting rid of a queue which has proven to be a massive bottleneck.

Comment: "It's so obvious to anyone doing any reviewing that you can't not see it constantly." The only thing that's obvious to me is that the people complaining about the approval of small edits to change formatting from one style to another, are bikeshedding just as much as the people proposing and accepting those edits.

Comment: "implies that I will somehow steal credit" And yet you said you didn't have the ability to do it.  If you don't like the names of the buttons, you can suggest changing them.  That's going to get a different answer than you asking for a feature that already exists.

Comment: How does being able to search for posts with pending edits help you look for posts for you to improve? If you're looking for posts to edit and improve you don't need to search for posts with a pending suggested edit. They're not *more* likely to be posts you'd want to improve. If you *also* remove the queue and try to replace it by letting people search for posts with edits pending approval then you've just made a worse queue that's less discoverable, resulting in edits sitting without approval for much longer.  At that point you might as well just remove the ability to suggest edits.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Why do you, as someone who  has not interacted with the review process basically at all, think that it's obvious that the concerns of the people who *do* interact with that system should be disregard, especially given that those concerns are specifically intended to address a problem you've also stated has been bothering you significatly?

Comment: Because I think it's clear that the review process should not exist in the first place (and am actively trying to propose alternate mechanisms for getting edit proposals considered and dealt with). My evidence for this is how much everyone seems to hate it, from every angle.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Then first off, you should *say that*.  But if you think that's appropriate you'd need to explain how you'd propose the site accomplish what the review queues accomplish but without them, or why the site would be better off removing them without making other changes to accommodate (it's not clear which you're proposing).  That's also most certainly not something to discuss in the comments of this post.  If you want all review queues to go away, that's a new proposal you should make, not something to comment on a post about why reviews require more than one person.

Answer (score 30):

Because we are humans. And if you can edit a post on your own, chances are you are focusing on the task at hand. But if an edit comes through an automated process like the edit queue the chances of you just switching to “auto-pilot” is high.

It’s not a perfect system, but it works if you understand what humility is.

Answer (score 20):

The answer is actually quite simple:

If you make the edit yourself, you just about have to take the time to read the post carefully (and if it's an answer, you already read the question and maybe other answers).

Thus, you know *exactly* what the post is about, and what can and should be improved, as well as how.

Well, that might not quite literally be the case, especially if you are mass-editing in a cleanup- / burninate- / retag-effort, but your involvement is at least an order of magnitude greater and thus your judgement equally more accurate than when simply reviewing edits in a queue, or even just those someone else made on the question and answers you are just reading.

---

It's just unfortunate when you shortly afterwards find something more to improve in the post, and it isn't yet approved. Which is why I submitted a feature-request:
[Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit)

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of the review queue that everyone gets this level of understanding of the post? _In theory_ when you review it you are suppose to read the post carefully. Of course even when I do my instant edits I don't always read it all (IE misformatted code).

Comment: well if we DO give that level of understanding of the post, why are people failing audits? We DO have robo-reviewers...

Comment: You are not quite expected to gain that same level of understanding, only enough to know whether the edit was good (though if you gain that same level of understanding, you get the right to instantly decide alone: "Reject and edit" "Improve edit"). And it's human nature (and actual neccessity) to economize as much as possible, which easily leads to investing too little. Thus, we need review-audits and multiple reviewers to boost accuracy and correct/suspend robo-reviewers.

Comment: Approving an edit is relatively anonymous, but if you do the edit yourself, or improve a suggested edit, then your name & avatar are visible to anyone who looks at the post (or its edit history if it's edited subsequently). I suspect that the non-anonymity tends to make people a little more careful. :)

Answer (score 8):

It is a pretty big waste of resources. But unfortunately having one SO user judge the contributions of another in a visible way simply doesn't work. Way too much drama when it is rejected and that person can be targeted.  Also the core reason that DVs are anonymous.

Rejections need a majority vote to be acceptable.  The minimum is 3.

Comment: "waste of resources" is a probably assumed not an issue given that there are over 30,000 users eligible to review edits. Given that amount of suggested edit reviews keeps low (for example [currently it shows me only 33](http://stackoverflow.com/review)), such an assumption looks sensible

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the explicit discrepancy is apparent in the disparate effects of the two actions.

If you make an edit yourself, nobody gains rep.  If you approve a suggested edit, someone gains 2 rep.  Hence the additional verification.

You can approve that rep unilaterally by 'improving' the edit, but that is enough additional work that it won't generally be abused (ie, like the first comment under Servy's answer suggests).  In the far majority of cases, the first sentence holds (rep gain is approved by 3 users).  It's not perfect, by any means, but it's better than 1, and the solution with Improve is necessary for the reasonable case that you do indeed want to improve an already fairly good edit.

Comment: If I upvote an answer someone gets 10 rep but there isn't a panel of reviewers double checking my votes.

Comment: I didn't say it made sense, I said this is why it is different.

Answer (score -2):

I'm unconvinced by the accepted or upvoted questions. So let us actually do a supplemental edit on the pending edited question for Pete's sake. The edit may be fine but it needs something more. We are blocked from any alterations until a further review gets done.  Let us get access for additional edits already!

[Edit] So my dodge now is to make further edits to "improve" the question further, since I can usually find something else that needs fixing and then approve that version which then sails through. Extra work, playing the game, .... kind of ridiculous. I've been doing this for several years and have proven my credibility.