# Increase Approve/Reject Edit Weight for Gold Tag Badge Holders

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

[About five months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212), gold badge holders were given the ability to close questions as duplicates. This seems to have worked quite well in terms of duplicates, however when a question is edited by someone [without enough rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work#answer-76284), a consensus must still be reached whether to approve or reject the edit. I often come across questions that I have a gold badge in that contain a suggested edit, yet I alone cannot approve or reject the edit, and must either wait for others to chime in, or "improve" the edit which might not need to be improved.

I would like to propose that the single vote close as duplicate gold badge power should be extended to cover the ability to approve or reject edits without having to reach a consensus.

A similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly) was asked recently, however no threshold was proposed as to whom should be able to have this ability. The accepted answer to this question cites the issue with users incorrectly reviewing edits, however by giving this ability to users with gold badges, you're setting a limit and basing it on the success of the ability to close as a duplicate change.

Finally, if the powers that be decide that gold badge holders shouldn't have the power to approve/reject a pending edit alone, then I propose their approval/rejection vote be given more weight.

Comment: I think the implicit threshold in the similar question you linked to was "anybody who has the editing privilege."

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that displaying knowledge (or whatever is displayed through rep on a tag) in a certain field doesn't necessarily mean you are going to be good at reviewing edits. The two are unrelated, really. It would make more sense to allow this based on some edit/review history criteria. Also, I would rather see the gold badge extend to other close reasons before anything else.