# Proposal: let experienced users approve edits when they view the question first

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

This is a follow-on to [Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly)

One of the ideas which came up there, which I also independently want, is to let experienced users (high rep, long time on the site, exact metrics TBD) single-handedly approve edits viewed via the "Edit (#)" link on a question.

This proposal does not change the edit review queue at all--as explained in the previous question it seems necessary to guard against people who approve all edits in the queue.  The change I'm proposing is aimed only at the case where a user views a question and then clicks the link to approve or reject edits on the question itself.

The reason I think we need this is that I have several times found myself wanting to make an edit (e.g. code formatting) but someone else with less rep already did it, so I can "Approve" their edit but it still requires more people to approve.  If the other user had not made the edit I would have done it myself which requires no approval (since I have sufficient rep).

Thanks to Martin Smith ([Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly#comment96643_271889)) and Squonk ([Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly#comment96656_271891)) for comments on the previous question which helped shape this idea.

Comment: I always thought this was weird too. I'm at the question, I want to make the edit, but two other people have to agree with me to do an edit I could perform myself. Seems odd.

Comment: I think this would be a great addition for the 10k or 20k privilege levels. Maybe they could start it at 20k and lower it to 10k if everything is going well.

Comment: I don't approve pending edits on the spot all that often but I never realized I was not just making the damn thing final... So when I approve an edit like that and then I edit the post myself, I'm probably messing things up, right? (I mean the edit I've just approved becomes void, I guess unless my approval was the last needed.)

Comment: @Louis: the UI does tell you when further approvals are needed for the edit you approved.  I don't think it's likely that you messed anything up.  :)

Comment: If you can find anything else about the post to improve, you can use 'Improve Edit', which lets you edit, and also unilaterally approves the suggested edit.

Comment: @Boann: yes I'm aware of that "workaround" because it was mentioned in the previous question.  But IMO if the previous user did a good job editing (which they often do), we should not need to "fake" improve it.

Comment: @animuson How would this differ from the obvious "improve edit" method mentioned by Boann above? (which currently works at 2000 rep)

Comment: This is a no-brainer.  The fact that someone else's unapproved edit effectively disables my editing privilege is a BUG.

Comment: I'd say run it off the sliver tag badge (like the gold binding dupe vote) rather than a fixed rep level because that encourages experts to take ownership of specific tags.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't see it as a fake improvement. Something is always improved by definition, if not the edit than at least the question or answer, because that is the purpose of edits, right? I would go with "improve" and add the edit you want to do to the suggested edit of someone else.

Comment: @Trilarion: I don't want to do an edit.  I want to approve the pending edit of another user.  For example, some questions are initially posted with horrible formatting, then some lower-rep user fixes it, but I cannot bring their edit into view of the world without more people approving it too.  It's the exact same edit I would have made, usually.

Comment: @flexo as always, tough for low-volume tags. In my most active tag, there are 636 all-time questions. I'd estimate needing around 210-20 answers to get to silver, becoming the second user with silver (the other user is not currently active). Gold would take another six years from now, requiring about 500 answers, more or less. I won't wait up. And that's in the most popular of my tags :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace If you want to make changes, you can hit "Improve" (or whatever the wording is these days). How is your own editing privilege affected by the current situation? (Note: I'm in favour of this proposal, but confused by your comment).

Comment: @Flexo editing a question is very different than finding a good duplicate of a question. A high rep user presumably can identify a good edit regardless of the topic of the post itslef

Comment: I think there's a bug that lets you do this anyways, assuming it is a question.  Change the url from `stackoverflow.com/questions/123456/whatever-this-question-is` to `stackoverflow.com/posts/123456/edit`, and you can do this.

Comment: Instead of focusing on the rep of the user, I think we should allow reviewers with the [Steward](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) badge for reviewing suggested-edits to do so. That way, we place this new feature in the hands of those the system already trusts. If we focus upon rep alone, or silver badge for the tag, I think there will be a lot of potential reviewers left out who could do the job as effectively, if not better.

Comment: @mu無: I disagree with (only) enabling this for Steward badge holders, simply because I am not one of them.  I have used SO actively since the early days, yet don't have this badge and may never get it.  This sounds selfish, but it's proof enough to me that requiring the Steward badge is too high a bar for this.  If you want to make the Steward badge be just one of several criteria and OR them together, that'd be OK with me.

Comment: Yeah, please don't base it on the Steward badge.  Remember, the issue is that I can't MAKE my edit, because someone with a lower reputation has made it.  This is nothing to do with whether I've spent enough time in the review queue.  The rule should be very simple - if I'm allowed to make the edit, I'm allowed to approve it when someone else makes it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This proposal was effectively rejected, despite being tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  As Nicol Bolas said in [his answer on a follow-up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373841/4323):

> The purpose of "Improve Edit" as a feature is to allow users with editing privileges to be able to exercise that privilege while an edit on the post is pending approval. You do this by essentially adopting the edit yourself. You can abuse this functionality to get what you want, but as you yourself recognize, you have to violate community editing guidelines to do so.
>
> Single-vote approval is not a feature of the system. It is not something we want people to be doing. You can create the effect of it by abusing the system, but that is not something the UX should encourage.

So the answer is no, you can't do this, unless you follow the tip given by the Community Manager in the other answer posted here.

Comment: Small nitpick, Shog is not a moderator, he is the community manager for SO ans SE.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks, I've updated that terminology, though I will note that hovering my cursor over the diamond next to his/her name shows a tooltip that literally says "moderator."  So I guess he/she is a moderator (of something), too.  Also, the `status-completed` tag which I asked to be replaced with `status-declined` is literally called a "moderator tag" when the site software tells me I can't change it.  The Community Manager put that tag there.

Comment: Community managers, as part of their role in managing the community, have "moderator permissions". The word "moderator" is also used to refer to a person elected to a position wherein they can exercise moderator permissions. To call Shog a "moderator" is a bit like calling the CEO of a company an "manager"; sure, that's part of what a CEO does, but it does not encompass all they do.

Comment: The thing I dislike most about this is that if I hit "approve" or "reject", I'm locked out of making any edits until the suggested-edit is approved or rejected, not even to fix tags.  So you have to read the whole question carefully to see if there's anything you want to fix (or decide that you're probably not going to spend a lot more time on the question) *before* approving the edit, in case your vote wasn't the last one needed.

Answer (score 13):

You can already do this:

[image: Improve Edit]

...Lets you instantly, single-handedly approve an edit. Yes, you *do* need to submit your own edit along with it - that's how you demonstrate you know what you're doing, by effectively *co-signing* the edit you're approving; if you misuse this, folks can both identify you (your name will appear prominently) and let you know by commenting on the post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I personally find this too hidden--the user's desired action ("approve this edit") does not match the button text, but does match the text of a button which doesn't do what the user wants.  This is suboptimal UX in my opinion.

Comment: Hey, you said you wanted this for *experienced* users... Well, *experience required.*

Comment: Yes, that's a good first step (and was already implemented, yeeha!). Still, if I come from the question, I will a) know better whether the edit is good, thus my vote meaning more has less danger, b) will return to that question immediately afterwards to work on my answer / the comments, so might have an improvement I could not have proposed just then shortly afterwards. And it's extremely irritating to then have to wait for others to approve.

Comment: Link to my new feature-request asking for that refinement: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-upgrading-approve-reject-edit

Comment: I have to every time give thought to the fact that the original editor will not have his name under the edit if I hit improve instead of approve

Comment: @mplungjan The original editor has their name credited for the edit that they did. It is approved and applied immediately prior to your edit, caused by you saving your edit. Your name shows where the post is displayed, because you're the most recent editor (your edit is applied after their edit). You can see their name associated with their edit by going to the post's revision history page.

Comment: @Shog9: Three years ago you submitted this answer and tagged my proposal as "status-completed."  Was anything actually changed, or is it your position that having people click "Improve" when they mean "Approve" is the correct solution here?  In other words, was my proposal implemented, or did you tag it status-completed without any implementation?

Comment: As I said three years ago, @John: "you can already do this".

Comment: OK, I acknowledge that you "can" do it, but I think the UX can be improved, so I started a new topic specifically for that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373839/streamline-ux-for-instant-edit-approval-by-experienced-users

Comment: But what if the proposed edit is already sufficient... (making a meaningless edit like `<!-- ignore this comment -->` is of course against the rules). This looks more like a [meta-tag:status-declined] than a [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Shog9: user202729 is right--would you please re-tag this as `status-declined`?

Comment: You _can't_ always use that button. This option is no longer available if you forget and just approve the edit at first. It could leave you with a broken question view if it's for something like code fencing.

Answer (score 9):

I'd still like to see this implemented more formally.

I can't tell you the number of times I've made a meaningless wording change to an otherwise fine question edit, where the only thing that really mattered was "adopting" the code fencing or indentation already suggested by a lower-rep user so I can actually view the question's code in a reasonable way.

Worse, if I forget to use the "Improve Edit" feature and merely approve the edit, there's no way via the normal UI to get back here and I'm stuck with the broken question until someone else also approves. In other words, it really is still **broken**, in that *there's not always a work-around available*.

Absolutely continue to require two approvals for someone working through the review queue. But if we came to the question more organically, and have the rep to make the edit, just let us make the edit.

Comment: I completely agree.  I wonder if now that Shog9 has left their official position at SO if we can improve this.  I'm not sure how to proceed though--should I "unaccept" my answer on this topic?  Creating a brand new topic to discuss the same thing doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Doubtful. shog was one of the good ones.

Comment: This is no longer a problem. With the new syntax highlighter, that messes up almost everything by default, there is (sadly) always something worthwhile to do.