# Approving Edits Vs Improving them

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118863/sql-doubght-urgent-requirement-help-me-plz#

When someone with low reputation suggests an edit, it requires a few votes by other members to approve it. This is understandable but if one of those voting members does have enough privileges to make the edit himself/herself without requiring other votes then why require multiple votes?

I'm asking because there was an edit suggested to that question and the edit was fine. If I voted for it, it would still remain pending until the required number of votes came in. So I simply improved it with nothing more than One capitalization and it was there immediately.

That could save the question from getting closed, although i know that question is terrible and should go anyway but I'm asking about general cases where the question is good but is not formatted correctly.

If someone with low reputation has suggested an edit then an edit of even a higher reputation member won't work until the previous one is approved or rejected, or if they go ahead and improve (even if they don't really improve it)

So my question is, if this can easily be navigated around, why have that limitation in the first place? Why not make an established member's vote binding when it would already be binding if the edit was by that member?

Like this one for example is good

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6310846

And this

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6310954

**Edit after the close-votes and discussion**

Is it hard for system to identify whether my edit review came directly from visiting the question itself VS going through the review queue to review all the suggested edits one by one? My question directly applies to the case where i was interested in a question and i was reading it and wanted to improve it but got a hold up because of someone else's edit requiring prior approval.

My question does not revolve around doing that from review queue. Its understandable to require multiple votes there as suggested in duplicate question. Over there one might require some counter checks but if someone was already on a question page itself and then went in to improve it that almost surely means they are paying attention.

**Edit**
There you go, one real example of this `prevention`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200190/foreach-in-one-page-php

I voted to approve the edit and the edit is waiting other reviewers' approval. Tired of waiting i went in to edit it myself and guess what, i cant edit it anymore after voting :)

Comment: "**if** one of those voting members" is misleading. **All** of those reviewing edits have 2000 rep, i.e., have the privilege to make edits themselves. One difference between Approve and Edit+Approve is whose name will show up as the editor: the suggester's or your own. If you are willing to take full responsibility for making that edit, you are free to do so.

Comment: "i was interested in a question and i was reading it and wanted to improve it but got a hold up because of someone else's edit requiring prior approval" The existence of a pending suggested edit doesn't prevent you from editing posts if you have 2000 rep.

Comment: Also see [Proposal: let experienced users approve edits when they view the question first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276648)

Comment: Thats my point. It does prevent. Try it for yourself. The only way to get around is to click improve for pending edit.

Comment: How is that preventing anything? Click "improve", make your edit. Or click "reject and edit" and edit from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question like this: "Why do I have to view pending suggested edits on a post when all I want to do is edit and I have the edit privilege? Why do I have to click "Improve" or "Reject and Edit" instead of being able to just edit directly?" Saying edits are "prevented" is not true and obscures your real question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i just edited the question with an example of how it prevents me from editing. So i guess my earlier statement was correct. It does prevent me from editing and to reproduce all you need to do is to approve an edit and wait, then get tired of waiting and go in to fix it yourself and you cant edit it anymore until there are other reviews on the previous edit.

Comment: Why would you approve the edit if you want to make an edit yourself? Click "Improve" and you keep the original edit plus you can make any changes you want.

Answer (score 9):

Because of roboreviewers. If edits could be approved by one person with a single click, there would be even more terrible edits being made and approved.

It used to only require 2 people on SO, but now requires 3, again because roboreviewers.
Same on other (smaller) sites - it went from 1 to 2.

Comment: But if one member does have enough privileges to make the edit themselves, why cant they have enough to approve the edit alone

Comment: Because too many people just click through the review queue without actually reviewing, so it needs more than one set of eyes.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The mistake you are making is thinking that rep *(higher rep more privilege)* correlates to better Edits, which is just not the case.

Comment: Nope i dont mean that. I actually mean If i put my name on that edit it goes through, but if i approve it on their name it needs more votes. If my approval requires more votes then why does my own edit not require them?

Comment: Edits *can* be approved by one person, *if they're willing to edit* - that's the entire point of this question.

Comment: @Shog9 "with a single click" - just added.

Comment: I think you can also note that on other sites it required only one vote earlier and now 2 - for the same reason.