# Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

If we approve or reject an edit (unless it's on our own post, or for mods), our single vote does not end the review.

While that's generally a good thing, intended to ameliorate the damage a small percentage of bad reviews would otherwise do, there's one disadvantage:

If one is active on that post (then or shortly afterwards), and **later finds things to improve**, one must wait for review to finish.

While that's only slightly annoying on SO, because we have dozens of active reviewers practically all the time, it still breaks the flow.

**Meaning the improvement might not be submitted at all.**

---

1. Please allow *upgrading* a previous "Approve" or "Reject" decision to "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" respectively.
2. In line with that, anyone who approved an edit should see the suggested-edit (maybe with a pending-notice, not only the suggester).

Comment: How is this different from [Proposal: let experienced users approve edits when they view the question first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/176646)?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: That proposal is about making experienced users edit-reviews count more (though only if they come from the question instead of the queue). This is about allowing a reviewers review being upgraded so he isn't blocked from editing.

Comment: Okay, you might want to clarify that in your question. It was hard to understand what you meant by "upgrading" the approve and reject actions. Personally, I agree with previous suggestions to just make "Approve" binding if you already have the rep to make edits yourself, but oh well.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Did my best to clarify. And the other is unlikely to happen.

Comment: Can you just always say "Improve Edit", or does the system actually check that you made more changes?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: It should check the same way as if you had originally selected that.

Comment: Related (MSE): [Editing a post with a pending edit after already reviewing 20 edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164381/200235)

Answer (score 6):

I love the upgrading idea and am very frustrated that I'm locked out of improving a post that I've previously reviewed. I fully understand the desire to mitigate roboreviewing, and I fully agree with the decision to provide the "... and improve" action instead of a one-click edit hammer.

But here I am, wanting to spend the time and effort to *properly* edit a post, either because I only later thought of ways to improve it, or I simply clicked on the wrong button by accident the first time around. Heck, even if I *did* roboreview something, isn't it a *good thing* that I want to come back and fix it?

I have the time and the willingness to jump through hoops if I have to (here I am, writing this answer on a 7-year-old meta question!). If it took answering CAPTCHAs until I got three correct in a row to undo my edit vote, I would. But as a practical proposal, I think it would be sufficient to have an undo button to remove my vote.

It *isn't* "only slightly annoying" for posts in low-volume topics. I've seen edit-pending (or close-pending) status stick around for months, if not indefinitely. Not only does the current lack of undo frustrate people in my position, it also renders the effort of the suggester for naught.