# Can edits we approve be displayed to us?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

It's not uncommon to see someone ask a question where the code is poorly formatted, and I'd like to fix it before trying to diagnose the problem. Usually when I see that, I just edit it so that it's formatted correctly, and then try to understand the code itself.

Sometimes though, someone else with less than 2000 reputation arrives first and makes the same edit I would have. When that happens, I have to wait for the edit to get two other accept votes before it will be displayed on the question page. The only ways I've found to get around this are viewing it from the review screen, which is inconvenient, rejecting the edit and remaking it myself, or trying to find some minor issue to improve the edit with (even if it's already in good shape). None of those options are very convenient.

So I propose that when someone approves a suggested edit that it should be displayed for them as though it had already been approved (reverting if it ends up being rejected). If someone approves an edit, they obviously think it's a better state for the post to be in, so I see no reason not to display it to them. Also, I think I remember having my own suggested edits be immediately visible to me before I had edit privileges, so there is a similar feature already in use.

Comment: And the option to 'edit and approve' the post after we approved.

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Show the edited form of the question when I've approved it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131417)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125909/why-dont-pending-edits-i-approve-show-for-me

Comment: My FR [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284973) goes a bit farther.