# Can I see an edit after I approve it?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

When users with less than 2000 rep edit a post, they get to see the edited version of the post with a notice below it saying something like: "The edit still needs x reviews until it's approved".*

When I encounter a badly formatted post with a notice `edit (1)` below it I click it, review the edit, and accept it if it's a good one. The annoying thing is that I still get to see the unedited post when I have reviewed the edit. It can sometimes take 20 minutes, or even more before it's finally approved. Also, I can't edit the post myself if I have accepted the edit and it's awaiting more reviews, thus I simply have to wait (often the post is close to unreadable, so I can't answer it). I know it's available for me, for instance by going back and look at the review, but that's unnecessary cumbersome and requires several tabs (one for the question, and one for answering).

**Feature request:**

After accepting an edit, can we please see the edited post rather than the original one, but with a notice: "This suggestion still needs 2 approve votes from other reviewers"?

If the edit is subsequently rejected, the post will go back to its original form.

---

<sub>*If you know the exact wording editors get, please help edit it.</sub>

Comment: I just noticed this is a duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288719/can-edits-we-approve-be-displayed-to-us?rq=1), related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131417/show-the-edited-form-of-the-question-when-ive-approved-it) on SE Meta. Seems like a popular suggestion.

Comment: you can see it in your [profile->reviews tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2338750/stewie-griffin?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (anyone can see it indeed, it's public by design). Find the post where you reviewed edit and click [Approve](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12136826) link

Comment: I know I can find it, I can just click the `edit(1)` button again, but then I need to have two tabs open, one to view the question (including the red/green editing markup), and one to write an answer.

Comment: I can fully understand the UI hint that there is an edit pending that you already voted on, that's a no-brainer. But may I ask what would be the benefit to you when you prematurely see the edited version as if it were already live? You'll basically end up in the situation where people may be commenting on content you don't actually see yourself.

Comment: @Gimby, to be honest: I don't have a good answer. But I believe my suggestion would be the lesser of two evils. After all, the original content is always available. I would prefer to see the best version of the post at any given time. You'll find obsolete comments on _a lot_ of questions.