# High-rep edit approvals from outside the edit queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

From time to time, I'll read a question, and realize that it needs some specific edit (most commonly, reformatting the title). I'll notice a pending edit on the question, and whaddayaknow, it's exactly the edit I would have made. I now have the following options:

1. Approve the edit, and wait around while it moulders in the review queue. Kind of annoying.
2. "Reject and edit" and make an identical edit, which would be auto-accepted because I have high rep. Counts as a rejection for the original editor, so that would be a dick move.
3. "Improve edit" and find some ticky-tacky thing to change (adding a space after a comma, say), so that it is likewise auto-accepted and still gives the original editor credit.

The third option seems like a win-win for everyone involved, but it also sounds like gaming the rules (or I wouldn't need to find a ticky-tack extra edit to make). The first option seems like What StackOverflow Wants Me To Do, but it also seems less useful for everyone.

What do y'all do in these circumstances? If a moderator finds out I've been doing #3, will he take away my holiday hats?

Comment: 3. is the way I'm going most of the time. Depends on how important qualified I think that question is.

Comment: Well, I had a feature-request sometime: [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit)

Answer (score 4):

I don't feel option 3 is bad and it is normally they way I handle these situations.  The way I look at it is if it the same edit I was going to do then there is no reason it should stay pending.  Had they not suggested the edit then I would have edited it with the same edit and no approval would have be necessary.  As you said this is a win-win, the community gets an edited post and the suggester gets the approval.

I do try to improve anything else I can when I pick improve and edit but like you said sometimes there is nothing left to do so I do what I can to make it count as an edit.

I understand why we have the 3 approves in the review queue but I don't think we need that when we come across the edit naturally and we go to edit the question.  Maybe they could add this to the higher rep privileges like the 5K privileges since it already deals with edits where if you review it from the post it only takes 1 review to decide its fate.

Comment: When I make suggested edits, I'd rather see an accept and improve than three approves. Even if it's just a space or something minor, it gives me something else to watch out for in my next edit. As someone who needs edits approved I approve of this.

Comment: "_I don't think we need that when we come across the edit naturally_" +1.  Especially, since I'm much more likely to understand both the author's intent and tag culture when encountering them naturally (since I typically look at questions in my recommended tags).

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, the problem with option one isn't actually that it might stay in the queue a bit longer, at least on SO, but:

   1. You don't see the edit provisionally applied, only the suggester does.
   2. If you later see any additional enhancement, you just locked yourself out.

   I made a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to deal with both some time ago:
   [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284973/3204551)
2. Regarding option two, you are quite right that it's a bad move, though mostly because if someone actually made a good suggestion, arbitrary rejections don't help them learn any better what we want than unjustifiable approvals.
3. Well, you improved by ... not improving? If you do at least a cosmetic improvement, one *could* argue that it's not harmful, especially as the post will be bumped anyway.

   Still, would you have approved of someone doing that edit, or would you even have dreamed doing so otherwise?
   It's a classic case of bending to the process because trying to repair the damn thing is an exercise in futility.