# Seeing the post-edit version of a post, when you've voted to approve the edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

After you suggest an edit (on a site where you don't have enough reputation to just make it unilaterally), you get to see the post in its edited form (with a little notice-box that it's still visible only to you).

But after you vote to approve an edit, you still only see the unedited form until the edit is actually approved.

For edits that massively improve the readability of a question, this is frustrating; it would be much more useful to be able to see the readable version.

Comment: Related, though wanting more: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit

Comment: Nothing on this in 5 years? Is this feature request being considered, or rejected already? No comments or answers on this post. I often stumble upon badly formatted questions (probably by new members), and someone has done the perfect job of formatting it. So, there is no need for me to "improve edit." I just approve that edit and still have to see the original version of the post till 2 more people approve that edit.