# Questionable edits: Can I do something proactive instead of waiting for their robo-approval and rolling back?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I'm tired of bad editors and bad reviewers, but **the worst is when after having successfully edited a post, I see a new crappy suggested edit enqueued and I have to wait for it to be robo-approved in order to then edit back and restore some sanity.**

When you make an edit that is seconds later defaced by a nonsense suggested edit, this nonsense suggested edit being of course robo-approved, is there another solution than what I'm doing?

It doesn't happen that often but really it's discouraging and I'd like to know if the community has some advice about it.

Comment: You could _"reject and edit"_, forcing an rejection of the suggestion.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh. I'm used to it in the review queue but I didn't realize I could do that in that case too. So, if I edit, go, come back and see a bad suggested edit pending, I can "reject and edit" from this dialog box?

Comment: @EricD. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When reviewing suggested edits, or when clicking edit on a post with a pending<sup>1</sup> edit you have 4 options:

1. **Approve**

   Casts your vote for accepting the edit. Three reviewers have to agree. (That is, two reviewers plus you.)
2. **Improve**

   Accepts the suggested edit with your additional changes. The edit is applied immediately using your [Edit Anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege.
3. **Reject**

   Casts your vote for rejecting the edit. Three reviewers again have to agree.
4. **Reject and Edit**

   Rejects the suggested edit with your replacement changes.  The edit is applied immediately using your Edit Anywhere privilege. The user will see this when they look at the review:

   > [Your Username] reviewed this Oct 6 at 14:28: Reject and Edit
   >    Community♦ reviewed this Oct 6 at 14:28: Reject
   >    This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.
   >   (more)

   The revision history will then ideally will have a helpful edit comment from you explaining what critical item was missed, or how your edit is better.

In both the improve and the reject and edit cases, the edit comment is your space to explain to the OP and the person that made the edit suggestion what critical edits were needed, or which edits should not have been made. Naturally as with any place where you can leave comments, [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839) applies. Also note that your account is the one that shows up on the post, rather than the person that suggested the edit, so you are assuming responsibility for the edit. (The same as if you'd found the question naturally and clicked the Edit link.)

*<sup>1</sup>If you have already reviewed the pending edit, then you cannot select a different option. Deduplicator has a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973) open to change this behavior to allow Improve, and Reject and Edit.*

Comment: I posted a feature-request some time ago to allow upgrading from reject resp. approve to reject&edit resp. improve if the review isn't yet finished, so you cannot lock yourself out from editing a post by reviewing a suggestion: [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284973)