# edit approvals kind of messed up

Tags: bug, edits

At around 2k reputation points we obtain the privilege to edit questions and answers, and our edits are visible immediately.  That's cool.  I have 14k reputation, so I have been enjoying this privilege for quite a while now.

However, when a question has a pending edit by someone who has <2k reputation, then the following two surprising things happen:

1. If I approve their edit, the edit still needs more approvals. This does not make any sense, because I could have made the edit by myself, and it would not have required any approvals!
2. Since the question has a pending edit, I am prevented from doing my own editing on the question.

For example, see this question: [How to use a Get method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977932/how-to-use-a-get-method-in-java) --it has been edited by this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520650/rhens who, apparently, at the time of making the edit had less than 2k reputation.  I approved their edit, but still more approvals are required, and I want to make my own edit, but I can't.

**Edit**

So, as @rene points out, this question has already been addressed.  Well, what I would like to suggest is that the existing mechanism for overcoming this problem is clunky, and a better mechanism should be in place.  Like, perhaps, the mechanism that one would intuitively expect: if a >2k user approves an edit, the edit goes through.  Simple as that.  No?

Comment: Perhaps also of interest: [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit)

Answer (score 3):

Not everyone is diligent in checking edits. The system requires 3 people (with >2000) to approve an edit (from <2000) before it actually goes through - or 3 people to reject for it to be rejected.

More importantly, you are not prevented from doing your own edit. If you think the first attempt is almost right but want to do a bit more, choose 'improve edit'. If you think you want to start again, choose 'reject and edit'