# It's clearly impossible to retag this question

Tags: bug, tags, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513333/how-to-retrieve-last-name-from-full-name-that-has-a-middle-initial

1. Add PHP, remove Javascript.
2. Can't make edit as too few changes.
3. Okay, so I'll add PHP first.
4. Try to remove Javascript, another edit has taken place already.
5. More nonsense with edit history, totally confused.
6. Someone edited an old version and fixed formatting but the tags were wrong. I hit "approve" so I can get back to tagging it right later.
7. Now I can't edit it since two other people have to approve of it first. I'm locked out.

Broken user journey here.

**Bugs that happened:**

1. I believe I couldn't change tags javascript -> php in the first place as my edit was too small? I would happily try to reproduce this but it's against the rules to try reproducing that.
2. I clicked "edit" question but was directed to approving or rejecting an edit instead, which was in the way of what I was trying to accomplish.
3. The edit button was available and clickable even though I was not able to edit the question.
4. I couldn't retag a question whose body had a pending edit. This is arguable but I think it is a bug since these should be unrelated.
5. It wasn't indicated to me that approving someone else's edit would lock the incorrect tags in for several minutes. I did not realize that decision I made had negative consequences for me.
6. I was allowed to edit a question that was being edited by someone else, then my edit failed.

Comment: Could you perhaps actually explain what the issue is? It looks like you just wanted to remove the Javascript tag from this question... And it's gone already, as of the suggested edit _you approved._ What's the _actual_ bug here? Can you explain, in a paragraph instead of a list maybe, what the bug is? (I'm assuming there _is_ a bug, since you tagged bug.)

Comment: @Kendra The *bug* is that I am a user and I tried to accomplish something and I couldn't accomplish it. Not being able to retag because I approved an unrelated change and was locked out is definitely one implementation problem that led to a broken user flow. Unclear why I couldn't add a PHP tag and remove JS, probably a bug there too.

Comment: Rather than commenting, you should be editing your question to be more clear. No, having to wait for an edit to be approved before you can edit is not a bug. That's fully intended behavior. The tag thing _might_ be, but you really haven't explained that very well, so it's hard to say for sure. Not being able to do what you wanted isn't necessarily a bug. Perhaps edit your question to be more clear, be a bit more specific on what exactly broke and any errors you got, etc.?

Comment: @Kendra I added a list of bugs that happened while I was attempting to retag the question.

Comment: I thought this was where the `Improve Edit` option came in? Selecting that should have let you edit the tags and with the additional edits, should have allowed the edit to pass, marking it as _Approved by Community_ and then _Edited by djechlin_. At least, that's how it's worked for me before but maybe that's a bug? **Edit:** This actually happened earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11335197

Comment: @War10ck: Yes, it comes in there. But only if you find the additional edit then and there, while reviewing the suggestion. I [posted a FR](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit) to allow upgrading an earlier review quite some time ago.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe I couldn't change tags javascript -> php in the first place
>   as my edit was too small? I would happily try to reproduce this but
>   it's against the rules to try reproducing that.

This is the only thing in your list even *possibly* a bug, and I can't say for sure because we really don't have enough detail here. It *sounds* like a bug, but you're not very descriptive here and that does not a good bug report make. In order for the team to have any chance to reproduce/fix this bug, they'd need more detail than you've given.

> I clicked "edit" question but was directed to approving or rejecting
>   an edit instead, which was in the way of what I was trying to
>   accomplish.   The edit button was available and clickable even though
>   I was not able to edit the question.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

When there is a pending suggested edit in the queue and you have enough rep to review suggested edits, you're taken to the review page for the edit. It's been this way for quite a while.

> I couldn't retag a question whose body had a pending edit. This is
>   arguable but I think it is a bug since these should be unrelated.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

While there is a pending edit in the queue, no, you can't make another edit. If you did manage to, and that has happened before, the other edit would be automatically rejected. But in order for that to happen, you'd have had to start editing before the suggested edit was submitted. (Or, use a workaround to get to the editor despite the suggested edit. I don't recall what the workaround is.)

> It wasn't indicated to me that approving someone else's edit would
>   lock the incorrect tags in for several minutes. I did not realize that
>   decision I made had negative consequences for me.

"Negative consequences" for you? How is it negative consequences for you that you have to wait a bit in order to continue editing?

If you thought the suggested edit did not edit the post enough, you should have selected "Improve" to edit the post further from the rejection. If you thought the edit was flat wrong but other edits needed to be made, you should have selected "Reject and Edit" to scrap the suggestion and start editing from the last revision.

> I was allowed to edit a question that was being edited by someone
>   else, then my edit failed.

[Your edit failed how?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35513333/2) That edit is by you, with your name, making the tag change you seemed, in this post, to have wanted to make. Or, at least, half of it. There have been feature requests made to prevent edits when someone else has the editor open, but that could lock the post indefinitely if someone goes afk. If you'd like that feature, find those requests and see what the arguments were against them, support one of them, etc.

Comment: Relevant: [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit)