# Implement the ability to retract approval of an edit

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Sometimes I click the wrong thing.  Sometimes I change my mind.  We can retract upvotes, downvotes, comment votes, close votes, flags, comments, questions, and answers.

I'd also like the ability to retract decisions regarding pending edits.

**EDIT:** - My question is not a duplicate of the one referenced because it is not a question about how to change my review.  This is a ***feature request*** for something that is as of yet not implemented.

Comment: @Machavity not a duplicate.  Your "duplicate" is a discussion about "how".  This is a feature request to change it.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit

Comment: Yup I agree - voting to close my own post.  Or should i just delete it?  Is there any value to leaving this here?

Comment: @billynoah I think there's value but it's up to you. I could delete my answer if you want to delete it, but I think you should just close it as a dupe if you feel it is (which may help others who find *this* question), and wash your hands of it.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things:

1. *Sometimes I click the wrong thing.* -- Suggested edits already require the approval/rejection of multiple people. So if you click the wrong button, make a mistake, or just make an honest misjudgment, just remember that you are not 100% responsible for the fate of that edit suggestion. If you accidentally reject an edit that should be approved, that doesn't prevent it from getting approved by others, and vice versa.
2. *Sometimes I change my mind.* -- If you find this happens frequently, then what you need to focus on is slowing down a little. Think a bit and be sure before you click the button. If you're ever unsure about a particular edit, or just not feeling up to the task in general, just [skip the review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/616460), or don't do reviews at all. Review with care.

Comment: I'm not in the habit of reviewing edits - this is something that comes up once in a while when I see a pending edit, click "approve" and then think - hey i'd like to actually change one more thing.  whoops! i can't - not without waiting for it to move through the queue.

Comment: @billynoah Ah yeah; well that [other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit) I linked to under your question has a proposed approach for that, too. If you haven't read it, check it out.

Comment: i was just checking it out,  thanks

Comment: after reading the feature request you linked I think mine is actually a dupe since that's more or less exactly what I'm after.  on that note, i'm voting to close my own post here