# It's annoying to do a day's worth of suggested edit reviews and then not be able to process pending edits on questions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Since there was the recent question complaining that the [Suggested Edits queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) and this is preventing people from submitting suggested edits, I've done some more reviewing in the queue, and reached my limit for the day.  Fine — no particular problem there.

*(I was puzzled why some people are able to do 25 or 40 reviews in Suggested Edits when I can only do 20 — the answer is that the [review limit depends on the fullness of the queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971), as pointed out by [Benjamin W](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)).*

However, I now can't edit questions where there's a pending edit (of dubious quality, as it happens; I'd be sorely tempted to 'reject and edit', but the question is also not very good yet), for the next 18 hours.

That's a tad irksome.  Indeed, it is a reason for not reviewing in Suggested Edits: it messes up the normal workflow to do a thorough job on the review queue.

I'd like to suggest that people with sufficiently high reputations (it might well be at the 20k level; expanded editing privileges covers what I'm asking about) should be allowed to do extra reviews, or override suggested edits, or otherwise not have to remember to go back to a question of passing interest to fix the editing after it has been approved (or rejected).

Comment: To piggy back the suggestion, why not remove review limits entirely at the 20k level? Since the privilege gained at this point is "Trusted User", if you want to go ahead and review 300 close votes, knock yourself out.

Comment: As for why some people can review 40 suggested edits: see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971); if the queue size is larger than 150, people can review 40 edits, else 20.

Comment: Related: [Don't count _any_ reviews against out-of-queue voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285473/603977)

Comment: @Steve Blame all of the users reviewing so inappropriately that these limits needed to be put in place.  A *large* portion of the reviewer base has demonstrated that they're not capable of reviewing properly; even those with lots of rep.  As a result, everyone else has to live with the restrictions that need to be there to prevent/curb abuse.

Comment: @Steve: Or to put it more simply, most users with the "trusted user" privilege sadly cannot be trusted at all.

Comment: @Servy one has to wonder why that hasn't stopped it either.

Comment: @Braiam Sounds like you weren't very familiar with what the review system was like before it (and other similar systems) were put in place.  It was a *lot* worse.  It's still bad, but it's notably *less* bad (or at least, causes less harm).  That some system hasn't magically made everything perfect doesn't mean it's a good idea to get rid of it.  In this case of this particular mechanism, the point is to limit the amount of harm a single bad reviewer can cause.  20 bad reviews in a day is a lot easier to correct than 2000.

Comment: @Servy yeah, 6-8 years ago, where most users knew each other, 2k was a mayor achievement, we had by all metrics a very small site. Right now, the sheer size of SO makes all those troubles go away (while presenting other challenges). You can't use the same reasoning today.

Comment: @Braiam You think that having a large site where people don't know each other means that reviewers aren't going to abuse greater powers if we remove a restriction put in place to limit potential problems of abusive reviewers?  Seriously?  SO being bigger doesn't meant that reviewers are all of a sudden going to stop reviewing inappropriately.  Oh, and 2k was no more of an achievement at the time this restriction was added than it is now.  It's not like this was added in 2009.

Comment: @Steve there's also a recurring stance from the staff (I've mostly read Shog9 on the subject) that they don't want reviewers to burn out, hence limits. So even in an ideal robo-reviewer-free world (I wish!) there would probably be such restrictions in place.

Comment: Can't you manually navigate to `/posts/POSTID/edit` and create a subsequent edit? Like, as if you had started editing before the pending edit was submitted...

Comment: I usually just hack the link and override the edit manually.

Comment: The system could just ignore the edit limit if you go the the post page, click “edit (1),” and choose “Improve Edit” or “Reject and Edit.”

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there should be a limit of X reviews of suggested edits from the review queue, but of X+5 of suggested edits.     This would allow someone that has reviewed X suggested edits from the review queue to still reviews a few more suggested edits they see on posts outside of using queue UI.

Comment: We can negotiate on the size of the increment (bigger, though I'm not sure I'd reach 5 all that often), but that would cover my main issue nicely.  I don't want to do more work in the main review queue, but I would like to be able to go about editing content even when there's a pending edit and I've reached my limit in the main review queue.

Answer (score 9):

## It is no longer possible to edit a post until the pending edit is fully approved or rejected

Not too long ago, Stack Overflow changed their system to make it such that the pending edit must be dealt with prior to permitting a new edit to be applied. Thus, if your review action was "Approve" or "Reject", and your review did not complete the review, then you will need to wait until the review is completed prior to being able to edit.

If you are wanting to edit a post which has a suggested edit pending, then you will need to use the "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" review actions.

I have not yet checked to see if the restriction is fully in the front-end, or if there is back-end verification. In other words, it may be possible, but there is no longer a "normal" and supported method of doing so.

### Use the edit links from the [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/346242/revisions) page.

If you go to the revisions page (click on the "edited X  ago" link at the bottom middle of the post, to the left of the post user's information, or go to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postID>/revisions`). Each revision has an "edit" link which allows direct editing of the specified version. When you save, the currently pending edit will be rejected as an [edit conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15370151).

### Use the "[Force edit suggested reviews](https://stackapps.com/questions/4274/force-edit-suggested-reviews)" user script<sup>1</sup>

The "[Force edit suggested reviews](https://stackapps.com/questions/4274/force-edit-suggested-reviews)" is a user script which adds a "force edit" link to any question or answer which has a pending edit.  This allows you to bypass reviewing the suggested edit and go directly to editing the question/answer. As with all methods of forcing an edit, saving your changes will cause the currently pending edit to be rejected as an edit conflict.

The links look like:

[image: Force edit suggested reviews]

### Use a [bookmarklet](https://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet)<sup>2</sup>

Prior to knowing that I should look on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) for user scripts, when I encounter this issue, I made a bookmarklet that forces an edit of the question or answer which is the current URL.

The following bookmarklet will open a new tab to edit the question or answer which is in the current URL:

```
javascript:void(window.open(location.href.replace(/\/q(?:uestions)?\/[^#]*#(\d+)$/,'/posts/$1/edit').replace(/\/(?:q(?:uestions)?|a(?:nswers)?)\//,'/posts/').replace(/([0-9]{4}[0-9]*)\/.*/,'$1/edit')))
```

The following bookmarklet does the same thing, but replaces the contents of the current tab with the editor:

```
javascript:void(location.href=location.href.replace(/\/q(?:uestions)?\/[^#]*#(\d+)$/,'/posts/$1/edit').replace(/\/(?:q(?:uestions)?|a(?:nswers)?)\//,'/posts/').replace(/([0-9]{4}[0-9]*)\/.*/,'$1/edit'))
```

---

1. User scripts are JavaScript based scripts that you can install into your browser to perform tasks that you desire (e.g. changing what is displayed on specific sites, adding options to pages, etc.). They are similar to extensions, or add-ons, which you can add to your browser. However, the potential for what they can do is less than an extension. In general, they are focused on changing, or enhancing, what is displayed in web pages.

   The code for user scripts is fully and easily viewable and editable through either of the two user script manager extensions mentioned below. There are other user script management extensions. They probably give you a similar level of transparency wrt. being able to view and edit the user scripts you install.

   User scripts are usually installed through a browser extension. The most popular are [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome, Firefox, Opera Next, Safari, Microsoft Edge, Dolphin Browser, UC Browser, etc.) and [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (Firefox).

   As Tiny Giany mentioned in comments, you can see the tag info for [userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) for more extensive information and links.
2. Bookmarklets are installed by manually creating a bookmark in your browser and then editing it to have the "URL" (Chrome) or "Location" (Firefox) be the code shown here. It is activated by clicking on the bookmark.

Comment: This raises questions for which, perhaps, the answers need to be looked on SO — such as "what is a user script and why would I want to use one?" and "how do I install one?" and "how do I know that the user script isn't going to wreak havoc on my system?" and "is it acceptable to subvert the overt policy on SO by installing a force-edit gizmo when the system doesn't support it?" and "why isn't it supported by the main site functionality anyway?", and probably some others.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info

Comment: Also, the system does support it, otherwise it wouldn't be possible. Likewise, the timeline view of a post is not linked anywhere but is accessible by navigating directly to the url, as well as any number of other unlinked resources that can be accessed by navigating directly to the url. Hell, if you know how to listen, the system itself tells you when the review task you're being served is an audit or not (not even by using tricks, it actually tells you flat out whether it is an audit or not)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have provided some additional information regarding user scripts and bookmarklets (& see Tiny Giant's comment). That and the links provided should address some of your questions/concerns. The only way that you can *know* that code is not going to wreak havoc on your system is to review the source code to make sure that it won't happen. Personally, I do that for any user script which I install. For extensions, A primary reason I use Firefox is that *every* extension hosted by Mozilla on AMO is manually reviewed for security any privacy issues.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, The system *does* support forcing an edit through the edit links directly provided to users, without any special additional installed tools, on the answer/question revisions/history page. Whenever there has been an edit, that page is directly linked from the question/answer. The links to edit a specific revision force an edit regardless of there being a pending edit. I have moved that option to the top of my answer, as it requires nothing other than navigating to the correct page (assuming that the question/answer has previously been edited).

Comment: woa. that is some deep user scripts here.

Comment: Re the blanket *"It is no longer possible to edit a post until the pending edit is fully approved or rejected"*: Perhaps qualify it to make it less dependent on this context?