# Close then Edit, or Edit then Close?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just reviewed a duplicate post (link not posted to avoid the meta affect<sup>1</sup>). At the time it had 4 close votes as a duplicate and a pending edit. I checked the post it was a duplicate of, and agreeing that it was a dupe, I cast the final vote, successfully closing it. I then reviewed the pending edit, which fixed some grammar and formatting issues. Being a good edit, I accepted it.

I then thought, shouldn't I have done those actions in the opposite order, accept the edit and then close? The reason I am thinking this is because the edit did not change the meaning of the question (it is still a dupe) and by accepting it, I sent it to the re-open queue. Am I correct?

<sup>1. If the link is needed to answer the question, I can add it.</sup>

Comment: It is usually preferable to edit before closing as the first edit after closure does send it to the reopen queue regardless of who did it. However, in this case if the question was indeed 100% a duplicate all the edit really does is waste some reviewers time/votes to leave it closed. And if it needed editing in the future it would have gone through the queue with the same effect again.

Comment: It's not a big deal in a case like this, but yes, edit first then close vote. This is important for salvageable questions on-hold, since only the first edit after closure puts the question into the re-open queue, and if you edit (or approve an edit) after closure, it robs the OP of the chance to make a substantial edit that will send the question to the review queue.

Comment: I have a faint memory of discussing this scenario before. That is, and edit which is done _before_ a post is closed should of course not be allowed to put the post in re-open, regardless of when the edit reviews are done. If this is so, then it is a bug.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The goal is to not have the edit place the question into the reopen queue. The question gets one free entry-by-edit into the reopen queue. In general, such entry-by-edit should be reserved for edits which make the question on-topic/able to be reopened. While it's possible that an edit by a 3rd party will make the question on-topic, it's much more likely that this can only be done with an edit by the OP, commonly a substantial edit.

## If there's no suggested edit: Close then Edit

It's preferable to **close, then edit**, because:

1. [Edits made by users who have voted to close, or flagged the question, do not place the question into the reopen queue.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078)
2. If you are editing the question prior to voting to close, then it's possible the question will be closed prior to you completing the edit. If that happens, once you save your version, the question will be placed in the reopen queue. If you vote-to-close first, your edit will not put the question into the reopen queue.

## If the question is already closed, raise and retract a spam or R/A flag, then edit

If you want to edit and the question is already closed, you can prevent your edit from pushing the question into the reopen queue by raising and retracting a spam or rude/abusive flag. Custom mod-flags (i.e. "in need of moderator intervention" flags) don't count for this and you can't raise a VLQ flag after the question is closed, so spam or rude/abusive are your only options after the question is cosed.

You can raise and retract the flag either prior to your edit or after your edit. Doing it prior to your edit will eliminate any concerns about raising and retracting the flag between the time you save your edit and when the script runs that moves the question into the reopen queue.

## If you are reviewing a suggested edit:

We want to prevent the suggested edit from putting the question into the reopen queue. We can't know if the user who made the suggested edit also flagged the question. We have to assume that they didn't flag the question. Thus, if their edit is applied after the question is closed, it will result in the question being placed in the reopen queue.

#### If you are going to reject the edit:

1. Review the edit and select "Reject". Hopefully, someone else has already done the same, and  you're done dealing with the suggested edit.
2. Vote to close.
3. Assuming #1 didn't handle the suggested edit, force the edit rejection by [forcing your own edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345380/how-do-i-edit-a-question-with-a-pending-edit-that-i-already-approved/363206#363206). If you skipped #1, you can "Reject and Edit" at this point.

This prevents the edit from being approved. Your edit, which forces the rejection, won't put the edit in the reopen queue. The initial rejection allows other reviewers to see that someone rejected it, and a possible reason why they should also do so. Having the reject review prior to your edit is a good thing if your edit is going to take some time. If your edit is going to take some time, you should consider making a small quick edit to clear the suggested edit and then spending the longer time on a subsequent edit.

#### If you are going to approve the edit

1. Select "Improve Edit", change whatever else is needed (finding something, if necessary) and save your edit.
2. Vote to close.

There's a brief period of time, while you're editing the question, where someone else might close the question (assuming, as stated in this question, that there are already 4 close-votes). If you're going to approve the edit there's not much that can be done about that. If you are going to make substantial changes in your own edit, then you should consider making two edits, one prior to voting-to-close, and one after. The first can make a minor change, causing the approval of the suggested edit. You subsequent edit can then take as long as you desire without the concern of having the question closed while you're editing.

Comment: *"Edits made by users who have voted to close, or flagged the question, do not place the question into the reopen queue."*, Why is this information not highlighted somewhere? It's rather useful to know. There's plenty of suggested edits on on hold questions that I would've rejected and implemented myself rather than just rejecting.

Comment: @NickA I wish I knew. There are so many little tidbits of information like that which can significantly affect what one does, but which are effectively hidden away in some Meta post, or comment, rather than be collected into the instructions (or at least linked from the instructions). I've found it *very* frustrating to be a conscientious user. Instead of being able to quickly read instructions which detail effects and provide recommended actions, one has to spend, tens, if not hundreds, of hours going through Meta posts, which you may only find by happenstance.

Comment: It would be much simpler if only edits from the OP could place into the reopen queue.

Comment: FWIW: the timing of edit and close voting / flagging may not matter that much. The actual logic for adding stuff to the queue doesn't care which order they come in, and the queue is "synchronized" every 15 minutes - if there's a flag (other than "moderator intervention") from the editor, the edit is ignored... Which means it won't put the question in the queue, and if the edit was the ONLY reason why the question was ever in the queue, it will be removed. O'course, this is all subject to change if/when the review queues are reworked, and there are a lot of bugs in that particular bit of logic.

Comment: @Shog9 The point of close-voting first is that you may not be *able* to close-vote after editing if the question is closed while you're working on your edit. If you haven't yet close-voted and the question is closed by someone else, then you save your edit, the question will be put in the reopen queue, and you *can't* then close-vote. The problem that is being avoided is a timing issue based on when *someone else* might act to change the state of the question.

Comment: Totally practical advice, @Makyen - just wanna note that the *system* doesn't care. Which means if you *forget* to do it in this order... You can raise a different flag (Spam is pretty much always available...) and immediately retract it to ensure that your edit doesn't reopen-enqueue.

Comment: BTW... If you wanna see a completely *infuriating* unintended consequence of this design, [check out this bug](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/why-was-this-reopen-review-item-invalidated/3351#3351) wherein the *reopen vote itself* (internally represented as a flag) invalidates the review task!

Comment: @Shog9 Raising and retracting a flag doesn't work to prevent pushing the question into the reopen queue. I've tested it a couple of times in the hope that it would, but it doesn't.

Comment: Not that I don't trust you, but... If that behavior has changed, I'd like to update the answer you cited! I need to update it anyway, since the "5 day" thing is also defunct. So, here's a test: [this should NOT enter the reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529129/how-could-i-write-a-regex-to-identify-css-margin-shorthand)...

Comment: @Shog9 I read the post to "check out this bug". If you don't mind, can you rephrase "The idea here is to avoid taking the actions of someone who is, say, editing vile language out of a post and turning it into an implicit request to see more of that sort of thing."? I don't understand what it means :(

Comment: @Shog9 Both of my tests [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/61782515), [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/61854129), entered the reopen queue within 20 minutes of my edit. I used custom mod-flags, which may be the significant difference between your test and mine. My first test on 2020-05-13: raised flag 19:23:41Z; retracted 19:23:51Z, before my 19:27:13Z edit; reopen review start: 19:42:40Z. Second test on 2020-05-17: raised flag 19:36:51Z; edit at 19:37:13Z; retracted flag 19:37:38Z; reopen review start: 19:55:35Z. There were no reopen votes on either question.

Comment: Ah, that'd be it then Makyen: "moderator attention" flags don't count. I'll update my previous answer when I get a moment.

Comment: @Shog9 That's quite a bit easier to do than to have the flag be non-retracted when the script runs to push question into the reopen queue. Thanks for following up on this. It's nice to have a way to edit without pushing the post into the reopen queue, even if it is a bit convoluted and consumes your spam/R/A flag. On which side of the functionality do VLQ flags fall? Even though you can't raise a VLQ flag after the question is closed, it's probably good to know.

Comment: The last time I could check, "mod attention" was the only flag referenced there, @Makyen. Reopen probably *should* be, so monitoring that bug I linked earlier is maybe a good canary here.

Answer (score 1):

If the edit doesn't change the fact that it's a duplicate, it's a good idea to edit it before it gets closed. This is true both for approving others' edits and for making your own edits. This is also true for other close reasons than duplicates, but usually questions that should be closed for other reasons than duplicate aren't worth editing unless it fixes the critical issues so that they don't need to be closed.

The reason for this is because if a post gets edited after it's closed, it goes into the reopen queue, but only for the first edit. So there are two problems with editing after closing it. First of all, it will waste reviewers' times in the Close Votes queue. Second of all, if the author doesn't think it's a duplicate and has a good reason for that, the author will edit to explain why it should be reopened. But if the author does that after it got three Leave Closed votes because of the other edit, it won't go into the reopen queue again unless someone actually votes to reopen it.

So it's usually a good idea to edit first and then vote to close.