# Do rollbacks push posts out of reopen queue?

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-reopen, rollbacks

We have all edited questions that are closed, when trying to improve grammar, etc.

This pushes the post into the Reopen Review queue and most of the time that is just extra work.

My question is if you rollback your edit to the previous revision, will it exit the RRQ? If it doesn't, then that makes no sense, since the post is just the same thing in the RRQ, and it's an extra review for people.

And if the OP edits to reopen their post, then it probably won't get reopened. So it probably needs to get fixed.

Comment: [Back in 2014 at least](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242584): "No, a rollback does not remove a post from the reopen review queue if it was entered through an edit."

Comment: @JeanneDark But if you clicked the rollback button, what does it do?

Comment: It's not really an extra review, it's the same number of reviews, it's just potentially less likely to result in the post being reopened

Comment: @Nick Nevertheless, it would help avoid a lot of confusion, right?

Comment: A rollback is an additional edit event. I'd be surprised if a rollback kicks the question out of the reopen queue. The thing which would actually disqualify your edit from putting the question in the reopen queue is if you've flagged the question with a spam, rude/abusive, or VLQ flag (not a custom moderator flag). Given that VLQ flags are not available on closed questions, you could raise and immediately retract a spam or rude/abusive flag before, or shortly after, editing. That would prevent the question from being put in the reopen queue. I don't know if it would kick it out of the queue.

Comment: @Makyen I sort of understand your point. But that's for other cases. The case I'm talking about here is when someone edits the question accidentally (such as fixing grammar, etc.) and then realises the question was closed. Since the question won't get reopened anyways, they want to roll it back, but the thing is it should get kicked out of the queue, since it's the same post anyways. I agree it should kick the question out if it is spam or something, but this is just for normal closure.

Comment: @10Rep Everything I said was about normal closure and normal editing. I mentioned raising and retracting a spam or rude/abusive flag, because doing so is a means to an end, not because the post is spam or R/A. Effectively, what I'm saying is that while you might actually be interested in specifically what happens with a rollback, for what you appear to *really* want to happen (i.e. preventing a closed question you've edited from entering the reopen queue, or causing that question to be removed from the reopen queue), you've asked about an XY problem.

Comment: @Makyen Ok, I understand. It's like a workaround to preventing it from going into the queue, but it would also mean a declined flag.

Comment: @10Rep It's *really* unlikely that the flag will be declined in the time it takes between you raising it and you retracting it, as long as you retract it immediately.

Comment: @10Rep If you're interested, Shog9 and I discussed raising and retracting flags for the purpose of preventing a question from being pushed into the reopen queue after an edit in comments on [my answer to "Close then Edit, or Edit then Close?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363277/close-then-edit-or-edit-then-close/363289#363289)

Comment: Well, I've come across posts in the Reopen queue with the leader, *"This post was edited after being closed..."* and then, in the place where edit changes are summarized, I've seen, *"no changes to display!"* Maybe that's where the edit that pushed it was rolled back? Dunno.