# Feature requests should not be left abandoned/ignored

Tags: discussion, feature-request-process

What are the rules of handling a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? Or specifically - *old* feature requests? Or namely: the ones I want ([click](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313401/1997232))?

What are developers implementing right now? What we should expect next?

I tried to search, but I couldn't find the answer about process. It looks sporadic, un-organised, not transparent, and poor...  ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387602/1997232), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387370/1997232), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131/1997232), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131/1997232)).

**Any** feature request (including every old ones) should have review period, maybe featuring phase, but once those ends **something** should happens. The answer from developers with results of thoughts and plans would be the best outcome. You know even [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) is better then the silence...

Should I make feature-request to request review of every old request? Observing the tag, I am seeing that not every *new* feature request gets its attention and I even found [my own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398451/how-to-reduce-number-of-thanks-comments) which I believe will stay like this until the end of times...

Comment: *What are developers implementing right now? What we should expect next?* --> it's kept a surprise until the release. It's more funny to discover it live, isn't it?

Comment: [Mine was left alone, but it got 7 upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400053/do-rollbacks-push-posts-out-of-reopen-queue).

Comment: @10Rep I have one with 120: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372877/8620333 and another with 21: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393400/8620333

Comment: There are 6000 feature requests and say 6 or so developers so that's 1000 each to update regularly. You want them to do that instead of doing any work? I guess that would put paid to the fun of discovering new features when they go live because there wouldn't be any.

Comment: You can find the latest changes [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/194720), but that's always after the fact... I thought I remember seeing a roadmap at some point... [Here it is! Kinda...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344178/194720)

Comment: @RobertLongson, I just want to discuss what to do to have no "ghost" requests, which seems to be useful (upvoted), but stays *ignored*... for years.  Your proposal I dislike.

Comment: @Sinatr So I guess they're looking at the feature requests, but they're not telling us. Then, when the features are done, they add a tag. I guess it would be helpful from their side if they add a comment saying "Hey, we might implement this idea!"

Comment: My "proposal" is simply the logical outcome of yours.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I dislike your logical proposal of mine.. wait, I didn't propose anything. Give me a minute.

Comment: I had an idea to keep one post where one Answer identifies one feature-request, preferably double-linked. Then one could vote on feature-request-Answers, and the top ones could be implemented and removed once done. This way the community could weigh in on what they feel is more important. I'm not confident that votes on individual feature-request Questions, like we do now, brings any sort of valid priorities.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - and here is the [Q3 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/23/the-loop-our-community-roadmap-for-q3-2020/). I am curious about the "new editor" that is supposed to be released this month and a bit worried about "downvotes research" in "inclusion" that took place.

Comment: Also, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1273439/feature-request-questions-that-are-upvoted-and-answered) may help - presently, there are 162 feature requests that are in limbo *and* highly upvoted (default > 10),have accepted answers and more than 1 answer (configurable). I think these can be re-reviewed at least ( the query may be refined to exclude more - some may be obsolete )

Comment: So there are at least 15 people as of now who thinks everything is fine as it is? Happy customers, huh?

Answer (score -9):

My proposal would be something like:

1. Let a new feature request stay open for `X` days and after that:
2. If votes are below `Y` -> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
3. A review is done by a developer:
4. Can't implement -> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). [Optionally?] leave a reason: comment/answer telling why.
5. Will implement -> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

After that I don't know. Seeing the road map would be cool. Seeing how developers are working hard is always nice. Not seeing anything (what if they don't work hard?) - is bad.

The idea is to define well `X` and `Y` such that developers don't overwork too much (they should work hard still!), but there will not be any opened posts for years.

Comment: So with this process you'll just end up with a bunch of feature request tagged status-planned that then never see any action for the same number of years because we get far more feature requests than we could ever process. The idea is to pick out ones that have high demand or are important to current initiatives, and try to get to the rest of them eventually.

Comment: @animuson, putting tag [status-planned] is like obligation. To change it *they* will have to do more effort then currently (by just ignoring). But you are right, there should be some follow up actions, I am just not sure which ones.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thanks for edit. FYI: Russians naturaly have problem with articles: *"Definite and indefinite articles (corresponding to the, a, an in English) do not exist in the Russian language"* ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_grammar)).