# How to review helpful+harmful suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Sometimes I encounter suggested edits that make grammatical improvements while also introducing grammatical errors. I'm never quite sure how to proceed with those. I'm going to pick either "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" so I can apply the corrections and fix the errors, so the end result will be the same for the post, but not for the user who suggested the edit.

I don't want to discourage someone if they're trying to help (and are helping at least somewhat), but I also want them to be aware of the errors so they can avoid them in the future.

I'd like to know how others decide what to do with edits like this. Is it just a judgement call based on ratio of improvement to error, or is there something that makes the decision more clear-cut? Does it make a difference if we're talking about code edits rather than just the question text?

Comment: Whatever you do, just don't panic... ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I try to avoid it every chance I get.

Comment: Relevant advice from the Department of Emergency Preparedness:  When in danger or in doubt, run in circles, scream and shout!

Answer (score 22):

If the edit is largely a good one, I'll "Improve and Edit" and fix what remains.

If it's a more-harm-than-good edit (and/or leaves more existing errors, clutter, etc. than it fixes) I'll "Reject and Edit", with an edit message listing what I did.

On the fence? There's [no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1324).

Comment: Yeah, this is about how I do it too, and I'm certainly not opposed to skipping. I just find myself on the fence more than I'd like.

Comment: Yep. I know the feeling.

Answer (score 12):

Something else I consider when evaluating edits is whether the errors are likely mistakes versus something deliberate.

For example, if someone re-worded a sentence for clarity but used "didnt" instead of "didn't", that's likely an accident. That's not something an editor that otherwise made good edits needs to be warned about*.

On the other hand, I once saw an edit where someone changed "I" to "i" every place it occurred in the post. That wasn't an accident, that was someone who thought they were correcting a grammar error. (There was a meta post about 'I' vs 'i' so we know that in some languages 'i' is actually correct.)

This is something the user is going to keep doing unless they're told they shouldn't do it. In these instances it's worth it to explain what you *didn't* change in your edit summary since the user who suggested the edit may read it to see why it got rejected.

---

*I'm assuming here that it isn't a mistake they kept making but Paul's answer already covers evaluating on more good than bad.

Comment: I agree that's important as well. I definitely wouldn't reject an otherwise useful edit based on some incorrect part of it that looked like it probably was an accident.

Answer (score 3):

Any of your available options will work to get the post into shape. What method you choose to use will depend on the state of the post as of the suggested edit (i.e. is it easier to start from the suggested edit or from the state of the post prior to the suggested edit), what you are wanting to communicate, and how sure you want to be that you did actually communicate with the editor.

#### "Improve Edit"

If you "Improve Edit", the only feedback to the editor is that they get the +2 reputation (i.e. it's positive feedback). Most users won't look beyond that to any subsequent edit, which is what your improvement is. Thus, this is the least likely course of action to provide any feedback to the editor, other than that their edit was good enough to be approved.

#### "Reject and Edit"

If you "Reject and Edit", the feedback is just not getting the +2 reputation. The user has to go searching for the comments on the new edit to see what was changed and/or the edit comment you left. While conscientious editors will do this to see what other changes were made, it really doesn't directly communicate.

#### "Reject", then [force an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363206/3773011)

If I want to communicate the problems and reject the edit, then sometimes I will "Reject" with a custom message explaining the issue(s). After doing that, I will force an edit and make the improvements. I'll use this option if I want to communicate and it's easier for me to get the post into shape by starting with the original, rather than starting from the suggested edit.

#### Any of the above and leave a comment to the editor

If I *really* want to communicate with the editor, then I'll leave an actual comment for the user. I use this option to inform the user of classes of problems which they may be doing, or might do, over multiple edits. Some examples of these types of issues are using code formatting for emphasis, changing code indenting styles from one valid style to another, copying code into the question from an off-site source in violation of copyright, etc. In other words, things which would be harmful if they are done on multiple posts.

You can leave a comment to the editor on any of their posts or any post which they have successfully edited. So that no other users are notified of the comment, I'll choose an old post of theirs which has no comments from any other users or comments from multiple users (i.e. if there are comments from only one user, then that user is also notified of you comment).

If you do leave comments like this, once you have verified that the information has been communicated to the user (i.e. the user replies, or has been active on the site after you placed the comment), be sure to delete the comments, as they will likely not have anything to do with the post on which you place them or be no longer relevant to the edited post.

Comment: The last part is the most important one: _leave a comment_. If you chose "Edit" instead of  "Reject", the editor should be notified of comments on the edited post. I'd like to see that added to this answer. I think many editors ignore Reject reasons, but comments cause notifications.