# If you are review banned, you can't accept an edit on your own post

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I am banned from review and I answered a question. Then the one who asked the question added a suggestion on the answer and asked me to update the answer or accept that.

When I hit edit I couldn't accept or reject, and since the suggestion was wrong I decided to edit that to update the answer with what user wanted, but I couldn't do anything with that.

This is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763477/how-to-search-the-value-from-table-with-a-static-value/64764084#64764084).

I was adding a new answer. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: No, it wasn't. You wait it out and then edit later

Comment: but it is 2 month i think edit might not be useful then isn't that better to allow banned users to review their own answers at least? or edit their answers when some one add a suggestion?

Comment: You will have to wait.  In the future, be sure you are more cautious, when you perform reviews.  The fact you are suspended tells me, you choose the incorrect option, more than once.  The fact your review suspension is for 2 months indicates you have been looking review suspended multiple times in the past.  The edit was already approved by other users by the way.

Comment: Other people can review the edit - it won't take 2 months before the edit is handled, but it'll easily take some hours (unless the meta effect kicks in)

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353859/323179. You can still reject the edit while banned but not approve it

Comment: You can force the edit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345380/13552470

Comment: Seems like users should be able to review edits on their own post regardless of a review suspension.

Comment: @dbush - You can always edit your own contributions.  My understanding, it's an all or nothing approach, and I strongly feel that users who continuously choose the wrong option while performing reviews, should be given a chance to learn from their mistakes.  The edit to the question was approved within hours of being proposed.