# Streamline UX for instant edit approval by experienced users

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

Almost four years ago I asked if [we should allow experienced users to instantly approve edits after viewing a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/proposal-let-experienced-users-approve-edits-when-they-view-the-question-first).

75 people voted it up, and 5 voted it down (plus more now that I've posted this!).  But after a couple months, a moderator answered by saying "You can already do this", namely that if you click "Improve Edit" (and perhaps make a meaningless change to the post, which of course is against the guidelines), the earlier pending edit will be instantly approved implicitly.

This is not good UX.  It is tricky, roundabout, hidden, and encourages the bad behavior of meaningless edits.  The moderator said of the workaround:

> Hey, you said you wanted this for *experienced* users... Well, *experience required*.

The moderator then shut down the discussion by tagging it `status-completed` with no action taken.

It is not completed.  3.5 years later, the problem persists.  Let's fix it!

This topic is not a duplicate of the prior one, because now we know that you "can" do this, but I am now asking to make the UX obvious rather than tricky.  I simply want the "Approve" button to instantly approve, when the user got to that page by first viewing the question.

Comment: I think the point Shog9 was making is that you require this to be for experienced users. Shog is saying that an experienced user would know that "improve" means "approve" here. I think it could be made more explicit, but I also don't think much needs to be changed to make you happy (namely, a button name change)

Comment: I'm not asking for a button name change.  There is literally no button that does what I'm asking for.  One button (Approve) does not instantly approve, and the other (Improve) asks me to edit the question some more.  I am asking that the Approve button simply approve the edit I am asking to approve.  I am asking for a solution which offers a smooth UX to users with sufficient reputation such that they can themselves instantly edit...I am not using "experience" in Shog9's ironic sense where it means "mental scar tissue that the system has beaten into you."

Comment: 2 clicks to "Improve", then "save edits". Is that really that bad of an experience to have to do that? I personally have no problems doing it, and it's extremely rare I do "improve" without changing at least a thing or two myself. I've very rarely seen an edit where nothing else needs (or could benefit from) improvement.

Comment: I am not saying the experience for when we need to approve directly is perfect. But I also find (YMMV, this is purely my experience here) that the need to approve directly is extremely rare, and that for the rare case it becomes important, the 2 clicks to get me there isn't such an abysmal UX

Comment: @Patrice: I have found loads of pending edits to newly posted questions which are totally adequate and deserving of approval.  The problem isn't for people who already have the mental scar tissue that tells them to always click Improve instead of Approve, but for other users who don't know this (e.g. myself, who had to post to Meta to figure this out).  Why make people jump through meaningless hoops of ceremony?

Comment: [There is a difference...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/proposal-let-experienced-users-approve-edits-when-they-view-the-question-first#comment165123_284901)

Comment: You're making this much, much bigger than it is. Basically, what you're asking is to lower the number of reviewers needed to approve an edit to one.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: "*I have found loads of pending edits to newly posted questions which are totally adequate and deserving of approval.*" Then approve them and move on. "*Why make people jump through meaningless hoops of ceremony?*" Because you shouldn't be using "Improve Edit" to do that. The fact that you "can" doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: *Then approve them and move on.* This isn't about the review queue. It's about question in our field, that we may want to answer, but which are e.g. unreadable due to missing code formatting, which the suggested edit would fix. If we could just approve it. But since we can't, we must add an edit of our own which may or may not be necessary.

Comment: The moderator on the other question didn't say "If you want to apply a post single handed use the improve edit button". Your last question also wasn't asking about that. It asked for how to edit when there is already an edit pending. This is what the improve button is for. If you now ask how to accept an edit single-handed without wanting to make further edits, just because you want to see them, that's a completely different feature request.

Comment: @BDL: I led with "[I want to] let experienced users single-handedly approve edits viewed via the "Edit (#)" link on a question."  The moderator said the Improve button "Lets you instantly, single-handedly approve an edit."  That's pretty black and white to me.

Comment: Yes, but the reasoning said you want this in order to be able to edit posts that have pending edits. It is at least not perfectly clear to what the moderator responded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The goal of the "Improve Edit" functionality is not to allow someone to approve someone else's edit with one vote. That's why when you use it, the edit ceases to be that person's edit anymore and gets your name attached to it. *You* are making the edit now.

As such, I would say that the UX is just fine. If you want to adopt the user's edit, "Improve Edit" makes it clear that this is what you are doing. The problem you have is that you're equating this to being equivalent to single-vote approval, which it very much *is not*.

Furthermore, statements like "make a meaningless change to the post, which of course is against the guidelines" make it clear that you understand that single-vote approval is *not* something people should be using this feature to do.

The purpose of "Improve Edit" as a feature is to allow users with editing privileges to be able to exercise that privilege while an edit on the post is pending approval. You do this by essentially adopting the edit yourself. You can *abuse* this functionality to get what you want, but as you yourself recognize, you have to violate community editing guidelines to do so.

Single-vote approval is not a feature of the system. It is not something we want people to be doing. You can create the effect of it by abusing the system, but that is not something the UX should encourage.

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful and well explained answer.  It appears that you disagree with the other moderator who clearly told us that we the feature I was looking for was implemented, and that I should I access it by clicking the Improve button.  You are now saying the opposite, specifically that you think unilateral approvals of edits are a bad idea, even for very experienced users who have just come from viewing a question.  Which is a logically consistent position.  Perhaps you could help me and others by changing the other question's tag from `status-completed` to `status-declined`?

Comment: If you'd post this answer or something very similar on the other question, I'd like to accept it there too.

Comment: @John Zwinck: [status-completed] is one of those tags that some moderators and employees seem to apply when it's "technically correct". I too am puzzled by the use of that tag just because you "can" single-handedly approve an edit by abusing a feature that clearly wasn't intended for such a use case. It's akin to marking a feature request for self-answering questions as [status-completed] (before the feature was implemented) just because you "can" do this with a sock puppet account.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Only moderators can use red tags.

Comment: @user202729: Oh thanks for pointing that out.  Well, we are now left in the awkward situation where the official moderator (and perhaps employee of Stack Exchange?) tells us to abuse the "Improve" button, which many of us do not wish to do.  Well anyway I'd still accept an answer from Nicol on the other question, and will now accept this one here.