# System design for approving an edit is strange

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For an edit suggestion by a low-reputation user to be adopted, approval by multiple high-reputation users is required. However, a single high-reputation user can approve and improve an edit by themselves. As a special case, the improvement by the high-reputation user can be trivial (perhaps just very minor edit, or even no edit). This is close to letting a single high-reputation user approve a low-reputation user's edit by themselves, and nullifies the requirement of multiple approval. It is strange.

One possibility is to let a single high-reputation user have the privilege to approve an edit by themselves, but other options may be possible.

Comment: It's not a loophole, it's a privilege of having over 2K reputation. It basically means the system trusts you enough to make edits without double checking them first.

Comment: If we can't trust 2K-ers this site is doomed....

Comment: @BSMP I am not sure if you understand my point. Maybe "inconsistent" would be a better word.

Comment: Agree with @BSMP. What *is* strange, on the other hand, is that [users with edit privileges can't *approve* edits by themselves](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That is exactly what I am writing about. I am not discussing whether users should be trusted or not. I am saying that this is a design flaw, much like an app that asks the user to select something when there is only one alternative to chose from.

Comment: I think I understand. You find it inconsistent that a high rep user can make a trivial edit no problem but a low rep user would probably have a trivial edit rejected. Did I get that right?

Comment: @BSMP No, you got it wrong.

Comment: Also, I think the `feature-request` tag should be removed, *Something should be changed, but I am not clear in which way.* It's not suggesting anything at all.

Comment: Can someone who does understand this question explain please?

Comment: Read it and then interpret it in the opposite context you understood it @BSMP I think OP is asking to remove the multiple approval for low rep users, although I don't see how it would be beneficial for the site.

Comment: @edrodriguez Exactly. And I added a potential feature request.

Comment: I still don't understand how that's different from my [previous comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307426/system-design-for-approving-an-edit-is-strange?noredirect=1#comment254622_307426), but OK.

Comment: The fact that something seem inconsistent doesn't mean that it's bad, or wrong, in any way.  You haven't actually shown that there are any *problems* created by the fact that the site is designed this way, just that it seems unusual to you.  In practice, there are good reasons for the design that was chosen.  If you think it should be changed, you should be prepared to show both significant practical problems with the current design (beyond just that it seems odd to you) and propose something else that would actually address the problems you've raised.

Comment: I don't think that it is a contradiction. The main reason for requiring multiple approvals is robo-reviewers. When you improve a post, you are presumably not robo-reviewing. And if someone abuses it, there are manual bans...

Comment: Of course, if the robo-reviewers ever find out about the "Improve" button, we're screwed. Shhhhhh! ;)

Comment: @Servy It doesn't cause an immediate problem, but it is redundant. Any high-reputation user who seriously wants to approve an edit can chose to improve the edit with trivial improvement. Then, the approval choice would never need to be used.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Not really.  Robot reviewers aren't actually motivated to ensure every edit is approved.  They're just there to get their review count raised as quickly and easily as possible.  Improving items (even with no changes) isn't the path of least resistance.  There are people that do actually want to ensure that inappropriate edits get approved, but they are *much* smaller in number than robo reviewers.

Comment: Question is clearer now, well it's close to, but it hasn't happened, and I think the reason for which we need multiple approval is because a consensus needs to be reached to see if the edit of the low-rep user should be approved.

Comment: @sawa So it isn't causing any problems, but it needs to be removed because nobody would ever want to actually use that option?  Perhaps you should spend some time looking through the review history to see how many suggested edits actually get improved and then consider revising that sentiment.  The *vast overwhelming majority* of edits are not resolved using "improve".  Only a few percent of them are.  So asserting that regular approving and rejecting is something no user would bother doing, when *almost everyone does just that* is trivially shown to be false.

Comment: @Servy Oops, forgot to add the obligatory winking smiley. Obviously improving an edit is much more work than clicking approve.

Answer (score -2):

**Disregard this answer, context of original question was different. Probably deleting answer**

For what I've discussed with other users, the only reason High-Rep users can do this it's cause they've *earned* their right to make these type of edits. The system trust them enough to give them this **privileges**. It may be annoying for some, but it's a rewarding system that ensures some order in the site.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point. I changed the wording in the question.

Comment: No, I understood. But the requirement its nullified cause they've earned these privileges. The system knows/expects they won't(in the majority of cases) misuse these privileges.

Comment: My point is that the multiple approval requirement is meaningless.

Comment: Then reword your question, cause you're expressing the opposite context