# edit questions with pending edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, edits

I have permissions to edit a question without peer review.

If a question has been edited by a member whose edits need to be peer reviewed, I see the "Edit (1)" and I can click it and approve the edit.

Then I get told that the edit needs another 3 or 4 or whatever peer approvals.

Despite the fact that I can edit any other question, I cannot edit a question with a pending edit approval.

At the same time I do not see that question in the list of pending edit reviews.

That does not make sense.

If I am good to edit any question, I should be good to approve a more junior member's edits and finish the paperwork.

If I am good to edit any question, I should be good to edit even a question where other edits are still waiting for approval from half a dozen peers.

For example: a new member posts some code without tags. Some other fairly new member puts code tags around the code. That edit requires 3 or 4 or whatever how many approvals from more senior members, but only one has been given.

Normally I could edit the question, add the code tags and be done with it.

But if some junior member has edited the question, we need to wait for 4 or 5 or whatever members to approve the edit.

This sucks.

If I can edit a question,and I don't need anyone to approve my edit, why can't I cast a final approval vote on a new-ish member's edit?

Comment: I don't see the post in my review queue. I open edit the post and there is no such button.

Answer (score 4):

When you click on the "edit(1)" button below the post, you are immediately taken to the review.

Once in the review you have 5 options

- **Approve** - Cast your vote to approve the edit (requires 2 more approve votes to approve)
- **Improve Edit** - Immediately approves the edit after you submit a subsequent edit to improve the post.
- **Rejected and Edit** - Immediately rejects the edit after you perform your own edit the post
- **Reject** - Cast your vote to reject the edit (requires 2 more reject votes to approve)
- **Skip** - Skips the review for someone else to do

> [image: Edit Review Toolbar]

So the functionality you want already exists to some extent, but you need to be willing to put forth the effort to provide your own edit.

As for why you cannot unilaterally approve the edit just because you have edit privileges, that is covered in the duplicate post [Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly)

To quote [Servy's accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly/271891#271891)

> Because there has been a long (and still ongoing) problem of users
>   incorrectly reviewing suggested edits, despite having the privilege to
>   edit posts without review. Too many people simply don't put in the
>   attention to evaluating edits that they do in actually making them.

So in order to unilaterally accept or reject an edit, you are expected to make the effort of adding to or replacing the edit with one of your own.

Comment: But I don't want to "improve" the edit. The edit is fine as it is.  So I click "Approve", but then I need to wait for 4 other folks to approve. Are you telling me that I need to click "Improve Edit" and add a space or other nonsensical character, so I actually "improve" and then the edit will be visible to all?

Comment: @teylyn why don't you want to improve it?  Is the original edit poor?  If so then click "Reject and edit".

Comment: @teylyn Maybe I miss understood something - you don't want to add your own edit, you just want to be able to say "I think this edit is good enough" and it is approved immediately?

Comment: No, the original edit is fine. I just want to say "Yes, that's fine, I approve". If I edit a post I don't need other's approval. But if I approve another's edit I still need to wait for 4 others to approve. That does not make sense.

Comment: @teylyn then it is duplicate of the post I quoted.  The reason why is covered in that answer

Comment: Pimping my related FR: [Allow Improving a post even if you already reviewed a still-pending edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284973/allow-improving-a-post-even-if-you-already-reviewed-a-still-pending-edit)

Comment: Whatever. The link @psubsee2003 posted is to a heated discussion. I just want to be able to approve, because I can edit any other post. I don't want to wait for xx other approvals when I edit/approve an edit.. Full stop.

Comment: @teylyn and why the current behavior exists is quoted in my answer (and linked in the dup).  If you want to propose a feature to change it then you should be able to address why that either isn't a problem or how you would overcome it.

Comment: @Deduplicator upvoted

Comment: I'm too tired to go through all this rigmarole. I can edit any question and the edit sticks. I should be able to edit a question with a pending edit approval. This is such a waste of time. I give up.

Comment: @teylyn: The problem is, that not only the careful users (like you) are allowed to review suggested edits. We have problems with inexperienced and so-called robo reviewers that approve inappropriate edits. This is why you have to "suffer" ;)