# Edit questions and answers - Should be applied immediately when approving someone elses?

Tags: feature-request

From the [Privileges help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

> 2,000 - edit questions and answers - Edits to any question or answer
>   are applied immediately

When reviewing an edit on a question, why is it not passed through rather than requiring the usual number of approval reviews?

As an example...

Firstly, you click edit when an edit is pending approval.

[image]

You approve the edit.

[image]

Now it waits for the requisite 3 approvals. However, since I have the aforementioned permission, if I simply made the edit myself I could have passed it through directly.

My proposition, make this permission push through edits without requiring all 3 approvals.

Comment: Somewhat unsurprisingly, this has been requested and discussed before. See here: [Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly) and the "linked" questions.

Comment: Ah ha, missed that. Thanks.