# Why do we "Approve" a suggested edit when we can "Force Edit" it?

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits

In the "Suggested Edits" queue, edits must have two or more approvals to get applied. Well recently, I realized that I could apply the suggested edit immediately by clicking on <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> and without any modification to the suggested edit just click on <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>. With this manipulation, the suggested edit gets accepted. Thus we don't have to wait for a second "approve vote" to see the suggested edit accepted.

By going back to the page I can see that the Community bot has validated the initial suggested edit:

[image]

While it seems fair that I can edit the suggested edit and bypass the second vote. It is quite bizarre to me that I can bypass it even without making additional modifications to the post.

Is this a bug?

---

#### EDIT: following the discussion in the comments I will try to rephrase my concern.

Improved edits are applied straight away that's one thing. That's not the problem here:

When clicking on <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> you are expected to provide additional edits or modifications on the current reviewed edit. Having enough reputation (more than 2k) you don't have a minimum character count: you can <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> and it will bypass other votes (even if rejected once) and apply your edit (even if inexistent, it will apply the suggested edit).

Here's the thing though: in the list of edits if I don't make any modifications and click <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, my edit will not be listed! So I'm pretty sure this fake edit isn't actually registered anywhere... That's the problem. In my opinion, the user making the fake edit should be listed in the list of edits even if he hasn't done anything.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or a design decision.  When you do an Improve edit it applies the edit, and then it gives you that current revision to edit.  So if you quit that edit, that revision is still applied.  Not sure if they want it rolled back or not.

Comment: This is abusive behavior, and if you a mod notices you doing this you can be review banned (or worse).  Given that it's a necessary feature if people are to be able to actually edit the post (and provide meaningful improvements on the suggested edit) there's not really any way around that.

Comment: Related, just to make sure readers know why multiple votes are needed for approval: [Why can't I approve suggested edits single-handedly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly)

Comment: the only difference between a `bug` and a `feature` is the intention of the developer. the only difference between an `exploit` and `abuse` is the intention of the user.

Comment: @Servy, my thread is not **in any way** an invitation to exploit this feature or bug whatever it is. I would not be here if that was the case. This seems to me like a bug, not a "feature" like you said.

Comment: @Ivan Like I said (and you acknowledged in the question) the behavior is *necessary*.  You can't just prevent it. What you *can* do is punish people that abuse it.

Comment: @Servy Why not just prevent edits with 0 modifications?

Comment: @Ivan Then people will add in a space, or make some other extraneous change, and you haven't fixed the problem, you've just made it less apparent.

Comment: ^ Yup, and there would be no way of distinguishing between a good edit that inserts a whitespace somewhere and a bad edit that does the same.

Answer (score 18):

If you have full editing privileges, then you have full editing privileges. It should not, therefore, be surprising that you have privileges to make edits to posts.

There are, of course, ways that you can abuse this privilege, but the idea is that the system trusts you not to abuse it because you have earned that trust by positive contributions over time. It's not a perfect system, but it's a fundamental premise for Stack Exchange sites, and it works pretty well on balance.

You are expected to choose "Improve Edit" when you want to make improvements to the edit that was suggested, fixing some additional things that it missed. You can do this because you have full editing privileges.

Although I follow your logic, in my opinion, there is no real problem or contradiction here. "Approve" is a two-step dance to help stave off robo-reviewing. "Improve" doesn't need to be, because nobody robo-improves.

Yeah, we *could* block "null" edits, but I don't really see the point in doing so at the present time.

Note that when you "Improve" an edit, you become the primary responsible party for its content. Your user badge is the last one to have edited the question, so any problems are going to be blamed on you. And, like all privileges, if you start abusing it, it is subject to being taken away from you.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my thread. "you become the primary responsible party for its content" I agree with you but it seems that if I don't add modifications to the original edit then 1) the edit is approved (that is described in my post) **and** 2) in the edit history my "fake" edit doesn't appear. Is that because I haven't  added anything? In my opinion, I should be listed showing that I have in fact **not given any additional edits**

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that your "null" edit did not appear in the revision history. Yeah, it probably should... That may be a bug. Not sure, you'll need someone more official than me to make the call.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: @ivan I think you should ask it as separate question "why null improvements are not attributed to one who improve".